# パッケージ宣言とフォルダ配置が異なるソースファイルをエラーとして検知するには

Tags: java, maven

maven では、ソースファイルのパッケージ宣言とそのディレクトリ配置が異なっていても、特にエラーにならないことに気づきました。

具体的には、以下のようなプロジェクトがあったとき、

```
pom.xml
src/main/java/foo/App.java
```

App.java のパッケージ宣言が、 `package bar.piyo;` であったとしても、問題なく `mvn compile` ができて、`target/classes/bar/piyo/App.class`が生成されることを確認しました。

このように、パッケージ宣言と、ソースファイルのフォルダ配置が不一致となっている場合には、ビルドを失敗させるようにしたいのですが、これを実現する方法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いくつか調べた結果、eclipse のコンパイラを利用するようにすれば、エラーを出力できました。
以下を pom に追加。

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
          <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

参考URL: http://qiita.com/ko2ic/items/331d7c1c02f60d24fe65